# How to make a Tableau graph with multiple dimensions in the same line?

Tags: tableau-api

I have the following table with names on column 1 and various questions that are answered 'Y' or 'N' and I want to create a graph as given in the link below. I want the Ys to show up in the graph

I tried IF-ELSE calculation but it gives me the the first condition that passes and ignores the rest and my viz now has just one mark per line item.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyv7x.jpg

*I've replaced the 'N' with blanks in this table here

```
+--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  Name  | Q1 | Q2 | Q4 | Q5 | Q6 | Q7 |
+--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| Bhansa |    | Y  |    |    |    |    |
| Chaga  | Y  | Y  |    |    |    | Y  |
| Chang  |    |    |    | Y  | Y  |    |
| Cooke  |    | Y  |    | Y  |    |    |
+--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Go to the data source tab, select all the Q columns, right click in any one of the headers and select 'pivot', this will pivot the data so that you have one field for 'Questions', this makes visualizing survey data much easier.

Answer (score 2):

As user Ben mentioned, the trick here is to do a pivot. You can do that by selecting the Question columns from the data source tab and right clicking at any of the header.

[image]

Once you have pivoted the data, you can create the chart as shown below. Please note that we are using a filter on 'Pivot Field Values' to filter out the 'N' values

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jose! I did not know this. It works flawlessly. How do I get the count of Yes, No's and Nulls?